# Rails route: define root to namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I've got 2 controllers:

```
app/
   /controllers
      posts_controllers.rb
      /mobile
         posts_controllers.rb
```

and my routes.rb looks like this:

```
root :to => "posts#index"
resources :posts

namespace :mobile do
   root :to => "posts#index"
   resources :posts
end
```

but when i visit `/mobile`, it's anyway rendering index page of first controller, also tried this:

```
namespace :mobile do
   root :to => "mobile/posts#index"
   resources :posts
end
```

but it's giving me error: `uninitialized constant Mobile::Mobile`
I want to render the index page of second controller, how can i do that ?

**Edit**

By entering /mobile i want to render files located here:

```
app/
   views/
       /mobile
          /posts
             index.html.erb
```

But it's rending files here:

```
app/
   views/
       /posts
          index.html.erb
```

Comment: You are doing well, just check that you `controllers/mobile/posts_controller.rb` class is like: `class Mobile::PostsController < ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
namespace :mobile do
   root :to => "posts#index"
   resources :posts
end

root :to => "posts#index"
resources :posts
```

instead of

```
root :to => "posts#index"
resources :posts

namespace :mobile do
   root :to => "posts#index"
   resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 8):

```
namespace :mobile do
   get "/" => "posts#index"
   resources :posts
end
```

Using namespace already prepends *mobile* to the names of controllers inside that block.

Comment: the complete routes.rb is in question

Answer (score 6):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 root to: 'front/homes#index'

 namespace :front do
  resources :homes
 end 

 namespace :admin do 
  resources :interviews 
 end

 resources :meetings do 
  resources :slides
 end

end
```

In **rails5** it works.