# Setting root of my website to a controller in a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, root

I'm going to spend some of my easter vacation learning ruby on rails. I've encountered a problem with my routing. I hope you can help me with this.

What I'm trying to do is set my controller *index* in namespace *home* as the root (the controller I want to use when I hit the root of my website). Note that my controller is called index and the method I want to use is also called index.

**Here is the structure of my controller(s):**

```
app
  -controllers
     -home
        -index_controller.rb
```

**My index_controller.rb looks like this:**

```
class Home::IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @testing = 1
  end
end
```

**My routes.rb file looks like this:**

```
MyFirstRail::Application.routes.draw do
    namespace :home do
        get "/" => "index#index"
    end
end
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857996/rails-define-root-to-namespace) question - but I couldn't make it work.

I'm using rails 3 and Rubymine as IDE (if it's any help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in my project:

```
root :to => "home::index#index"
```

The structure is always the same with `root :to` (which is what is used to define the root route :))

```
root :to => "controller_name#action"
```

Your namespaced controller here is simply named `home::index`.

Comment: I am curious as to what the difference between using :: and / in the root is? Both seems to work.

Comment: I don't know if there is a big difference, I'm simply used to write the controller name instead of its path. You can choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try doing like this in routes,

```
root :to => "controller#action"
```